# Approximation of $\zeta(3)$

Tags: approximation, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions

What can we add to approximation (or perform)
$$\zeta(3)\approx\sqrt{\frac{4}{5}+\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\tanh(2\pi)}$$
for transform it into the equation?

Comment: How did you get this approximation?

Comment: @Klangen, first, English is not my native, so if there will be some mistakes, sorry. I see that your last answers all about $\zeta(3)$. Now you came here and see this strange approximation. But how long can someone keep secret of $\zeta(2n+1)$ (or more general formula) if he will find it? So you may be sure that this is no more, than lucky guess.

Answer (score 6):

No closed form is known for [Apéry's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant), so there is no known way to convert your approximation into an equation.
$$\frac{11888848 }{11888849} \sqrt{\frac{4}{5}+\frac{\pi ^2}{6}-\tanh (2 \pi )}$$
is a slight, boring improvement, reducing the relative error by about $7$ [orders of magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude).